# Create a GUI for a deployment server

Tags: networking, server, gui

That's my first question. Also, I'm French so I'm sorry for the mistakes I'll make.

Currently, I know how to create a deployment server (TFTP, DHCP and some ISO).

I also know some "soft" that can do local deployment (like fog) but they don't provide a true user-friendly interface (or a way to make it in html or anything else)

But I want the user booting my server to have a graphical interface where he can select which OS and which pilots.

I don't know if this is clear; I'll edit if you have a problem understanding me.

**Answers to comments** :

> 'select which OS and pilots': are you thinking of dual boot system
>   (Windows / Ubuntu) or of multplie linux flavors? – Marc Vanhoomissen

The client starts his computer in PXE and then selects *I want to install Windows server 2008 x64* and clicks <kbd>install</kbd> or *I want Windows 10 with the pilots for my network card and also geforce experience*. I've already seen this in a company, so I know it's possible; I just don't know how.

> Use syslinux to create a menu to be shown over PXE/TFTP booting from the linked post. – muru

It looks good, I'll check this out.

> Possible duplicate of PXE Boot Server Installation Steps in Ubuntu Server VM – muru

No, I know how to make a PXE server (or at least, I can find out easily). The thing I'm asking is how to make a friendly-user interface with checkbox and other utilities (I think I can build it like a simple HTML form).

Comment: You mean, he can access a webpage during the boot session ?

Comment: 'select which OS and pilots': are you thinking of dual boot system (Windows / Ubuntu) or of multplie linux flavors?

Comment: The client start his computer in PXE and then he select "I want to install Windows server 2008 x64" and click install or "I want Windows 10 with the pilots for my network card and also geforce experience" I already seen this in a company, so I know it's possible i just don't know how

Comment: @LucasAzoulay please expand the question with  the comments you added ;)

Comment: Use syslinux to create a menu to be shown over PXE/TFTP booting from the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

As muru said in the comments, syslinux seems to match my attempts.

Here is a link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSLINUX

Hope it can help someone ;)

I'll update it later to transform it into a real answer.

Comment: a link to a possible solution or guide is not considered a good answer on Stack Exchange sites. Please could you expand your answer, preferably with concrete instructions. For example, you could document your own steps.

Comment: Well I didn't done this PXE server with syslinux yet, I need to do it but i'm a bit little in time, should I delete my answer ?

Comment: I don't think you should delete your answer, but it would be awesome if you could please come back and expand it later

Comment: Ok, i'll do it if i can ;)